# MySQL issue with foreign key validation

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently self-teaching myself mySQL and i've come across an issue when inserting new rows into my sales database.

Every time a sale of a product is made, a new row is added to the sales database, which includes the id of the buyer (foreign key from users table) and the name of the buyer (foreign key from users table).

However my problem is as follows. If I insert a new record into the sales table for a user with `id=10` and I incorrectly input `name='Peter Smith'` instead of `name='Roger Smith'`, it is successful even though `'Peter Smith'` is not the name of the person with `id=10` in the users table.

Could anyone point me in the direction of where I have gone wrong? Many thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `sales` (
`salesid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`productname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`productprice` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`salesid`),
KEY `FK_sales` (`userid`),
KEY `FK_name` (`user_name`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_name` FOREIGN KEY (`user_name`) REFERENCES `users` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_sales` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you've gone wrong is update anomalies, because the implementation violates third normal form (3NF).

> Each and every attribute is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key. So help me Codd.

---

In your model, `user_name` in the `sales` table is dependent on key of the `sales` table. It sounds like you want it to be dependent on the `userid` column.

The simple fix is to *remove* the `user_name` column from the `sales` table. When you need to return the user_name, do a lookup in the `users` table based on user_id. As an example, a JOIN operation to the `users` table.

```
SELECT u.name AS user_name 
     , s.userid
     , s.productprice
     , ...
  FROM sales s
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = s.userid
```

With this approach, we've avoided storing redundant information. The e `name` attribute is dependent *only* on the `id` column in the `users` table.

---

If there's a strong need to store `user_name` on the `sales` table, then the application logic will need to enforce the rule that the `user_name` on a row in the `sales` table will need to be the same as the `name` column in the corresponding row in `users` table.  There are no declarative constraints that will enforce that kind of rule

(A foreign key constraint only enforces the rule that the value must appear in *some* row in the referenced table.)

It is possible to add BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers to enforce the rule, and do the lookup and automatically populate the `user_name` column.

Comment: Actually the sales table and the user table aren't even in 1NF because there's no natural key in either one.